# MySQL - Update table and set column value equal to different of current row value minus previous row value

Tags: mysql, set

I have a table with 20 columns, and I want to populate the last column of each row with the difference between the value of this row (for this column) minus the value of the previous row for the same column.. (if the time on the current row is higher than the time on the previous row)

```
    update tbl set column_with_differences =
    (select case when (a.columnWithValueOnSameRow-b.columnWithValueOnPreviousRow) is null
    then a.columnWithValueOnSameRow  else a.columnWithValueOnSameRow-b.columnWithValueOnPreviousRow end       
as tot
    from tbl a left join 
    tbl b
    on a.time > b.time);
```

the columns with the values and the time are varchar(10).

I am getting a MySQL error

```
ERROR 1093 (HY000): You can't specify target table 'tbl' for update in FROM clause
```

I know it is normal to get this error since I am attempting to update the table while selecting from it..

Any way to avoid getting this error and actually updating the values on the table with the differences of the current row minus the previous row ?

Thanks a lot.

EDIT :

My bad, I forgot to mention that I also have a date column, as well as a unique ID for each row...

Comment: Beware: MySQL contains *no inherent concept* of the order of rows. A SELECT query without an ORDER BY clause is free to return the rows in the result set in any order whatsoever.  So if you want to identify the "previous" row to any row, you need to start with an ordering.  If you use the "default order", whatever that happens to be, *you will be sorry* when your table gets bigger.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is a bit complicated.  In a `select` query, you could use variables or do the following to get the previous value,

```
select tbl.*,
       (select prev.col
        from tbl prev
        where prev.time < tbl.time
        order by time desc
        limit 1
       ) as prev_col
from tbl;
```

This assumes that the column `time` is the ordering column.  You can then do an update by joining back to this, once again, with an assumption -- that `time` uniquely identifies each row:

```
update tbl t join
       (select tbl.*,
              (select prev.col
               from tbl prev
               where prev.time < tbl.time
               order by time desc
               limit 1
              ) as prev_col
        from tbl
       ) tt
       on tt.time = t.time
    set t.diff = t.col - tt.prev_col;
```

Comment: Hi Gordon, thanks for your answer. I forgot to mention that each row also has a date and a unique ID, so row can have the same time, but they will have different dates .. maybe this can help u with ur query and sorry for not mentioning it in my initial post.